# Sucrase moves only JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, build

Im using the lib [`sucrase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sucrase) to use ES6 modules in NodeJS(`import/export`) and i'm using the follow command to generate a build of my project in commonJ:
`sucrase ./src -d ./build --transforms imports` where `./src` is my project folder and `./build` is the output. When the process is finished i have a `build` folder with my `javascripts` files converted to commonJS but the assets files and every no-JS files are moved to this `build` folder, like images and css files in `public` directory or PUG files in `views`, only the JS files and directories are moved. I dont know if is possible do this with `sucrase` cause i've already read the doc, but maybe its possible do with another lib(sucrase with other lib).

My project structure(`src`)

```
│   app.js
│
├───public
│   │
│   ├───images
│   │      some-image.png
│   │
│   ├───javascripts
│   │      script.js
│   │
│   └───stylesheets
│          styles.min.css
│
├───routes
│       index.js
│
└───views
    │   index.pug
    │   layout.pug
    │
    └───parts
            footer.pug
            header.pug
```

My project structure after converted(`build`)

```
│   app.js
│
├───public
│   │
│   ├───images
│   │
│   ├───javascripts
│   │      script.js
│   │
│   └───stylesheets
│
├───routes
│       index.js
│
└───views
    └───parts
```

Answer (score 6):

I read [sucrase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sucrase) document and found that ONLY support load JS files (JSX, TS, etc). If you want to load another kind of files, use [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

Sucrase also offers a package called [@sucrase/webpack-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sucrase/webpack-loader). You can give it a try, but I'm not sure it supports to load images, non-JS files and so on.

Last but not least, `sucrase` documentation is not great, and I highly recommend not using it because you will have trouble with it community like this. Use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) instead if you want to deep dive into bundler. For modern approach for example with ReactJS, I higly recommend using [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) to forget all things about bundler, you totally can move your react app into gatsby easily.

Maybe this might not help you resolve problem, but I hope I can give you a picture on your problem. Sharing is more important thing. Good luck!